# How to use timestamp in Apache CustomLog directive

Tags: apache-2.4, logging, apache2

I was trying to use a timestamp in Apache CustomLog directive so that a new file is created every hour

I set it to:

```
CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/healthd/application.log.%{%Y-%m-%d-%H}t" healthd
```

And it created a file with that literal name:

```
$ ls -la
total 20
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4096 Feb 11 16:24 .
drwxrwxrwx 4 root root 4096 Feb 11 16:24 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9919 Feb 11 16:36 application.log.%{%Y-%m-%d-%H}t
```

Whats the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to use Apache rotatelogs.

It can be installed with `apt-get install apache2-utils` on Debian.

Apache must be configured to use it:

```
CustomLog "|/usr/bin/rotatelogs -l /var/log/apache2/healthd/application.log.%Y-%m-%d-%H 3600" logformat
```